# Auto-Resizing JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea, autoresize

I want my JTextArea to resize itself (expand vertically) when the last line (that the text area's height can offer) is reached and the user wants to start a new line. You know, like the textbox in MSWord.

I have an idea to use `getLineCount()` and determine (if necessary) the new height of the JTextArea. Do you have, or know of better approaches for implementing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the `JTextArea` always has the correct size so all lines of text are visible. What you experience is probably that you wrapped the text area in a `JScrollPane`. Just omit the scroll pane and make the text area a direct child of the container.

Another solution is to listen to resize events of the text area and size the scroll pane accordingly. This way, you can grow to a certain size and then start to display scroll bars (for example, when someone pastes 500KB of text into the text area).

Comment: I just add the JTextArea to a JPanel. Is it something with setting the size? But if I don't set the size, then it does not show up.

Comment: You just have to set the size of the JPanel so that the text area can grow. The text area should automatically adjust to fit the size of the text inside.

Comment: well, it didn't work. BTW I switched to using JTextPane, but still the problem with the expansion continues

Comment: hmm, I think it's a problem with setting the text. I use setText() but probably i should use insertString(). i'll try that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. From my tests, I do not believe that the JTextArea sets its size dynamically. Instead, its size seems to be limited by its container (a JPanel in my case). However, the JTextArea does change its preferred size based on the text it contains. From the documentation:

> java.awt.TextArea has two properties rows and columns that are used to determine the preferred size. JTextArea uses these properties to indicate the preferred size of the viewport when placed inside a JScrollPane to match the functionality provided by java.awt.TextArea. JTextArea has a preferred size of what is needed to display all of the text, so that it functions properly inside of a JScrollPane. If the value for rows or columns is equal to zero, the preferred size along that axis is used for the viewport preferred size along the same axis.

Answer (score 1):

Go to JTextArea "**Properties**" - checklist "**lineWrap**".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem，I put the JTextArea into a JScrollPane and set the preferred size of JTextArea, and I believe that's the cause of the problem.

So the right solution is to put the JTextArea into a JScrollPane, and don't touch the preferred size of JTextArea, set JScrollPane's instead.